# Asynchronous JAX-RS call never responds

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, jax-rs, wildfly

I have a REST resource creating a `User` POJO instance within the execution of a `UserCreateRunnable` instance (as a `Runnable` member class) and submitting it to a `ManagedExecutorService`.

Then just when the `User` instance should be persisted, the whole execution holds, nothing is processed anymore, no Exceptions at all and the REST call gets never responded.
The last log record I get is "UCR.run: User created, persist..."

Here is what I get with curl:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "User-Email:joe@user.com" -H "Auth-Hash:0BEEC7B5EA3F0FDBC95D0DD47F3C5BC275DA8A33" http://localhost:8080/nb-ee-rs/v1/user/create/1
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> PUT /nb-ee-rs/v1/user/create/1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> User-Email:joe@user.com
> Auth-Hash:0BEEC7B5EA3F0FDBC95D0DD47F3C5BC275DA8A33
>
```

After executing the command the prompt never returns.

Further calls to different REST resources within the same project respond normally, just like everything else so I doubt there is a config issue.

Before trying to process this REST resource asynchronously, I had a synchronous version (same code as in `UserCreateRunnable.run()` inlined into the `UserResource.create(...)` method) which worked like a charm.

So I guess there is some issue with the concurrency... unfortunately, I can't figure out what's wrong with the code provided below.

I use Wildfly,  Java EE 7, Eclipselink.

```
@Stateless
@Path( "/user" )
public class UserResource {

    private static final Logger     LOG = Logger.getLogger( "xyz" );

    @PersistenceContext( unitName = "xyz" )
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    EJBContext ejbContext;

    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;

    @EJB
    private EmailBean       emailBean;


    @PUT
    @Path( "/create/{type: [0-9]}" )
    @Produces( "text/plain" )
    public void create( @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResp, @Context final HttpHeaders hh, @PathParam("type") final int type ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        if( type == User.USER_TYPE_EMAIL ) {

            LOG.log( Level.INFO, "REST PUT: user/create/email-user, headers:{0}", ProjectStatics.buildHeaderString( hh.getRequestHeaders() ) );

            String email    = hh.getHeaderString( User.REST_HEADER_USER_EMAIL );
            String authHash = hh.getHeaderString( User.REST_HEADER_AUTH_HASH );
            UserCreateRunnable ucr = new UserCreateRunnable( asyncResp, type, email, authHash );
            managedExecutorService.execute( ucr );

        }
        else
            asyncResp.resume( Response.status( Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST ).build() );

    }


    private final class UserCreateRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final int type;

        private String email;

        private final String authHash;

        private final AsyncResponse asynResp;


        UserCreateRunnable( AsyncResponse asynResp, int type, String email, String authHash ) {
            this.type = type;
            this.email = email;
            this.authHash = authHash;
            this.asynResp = asynResp;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

            LOG.log( Level.INFO, "UCR.run: ar={0}, type={1}, email={2}, authHash={3}, em={4}, ejbCtx={5}, emailBean={6}", new Object[] {asynResp,type,email,authHash,em,ejbContext,emailBean} );

            // check email
            if( email == null  ||  email.isEmpty()  ||  !email.contains( "@" )  ||  !email.contains( "." ) ) {

                LOG.log( Level.WARNING, "UCR.run: AR:{0}", asynResp );
                asynResp.resume( Response.status( Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST ).entity( Integer.toString( User.REST_RESPONSE_WRONG_EMAIL ) ).build() );
                return;
            }


            // check pwd hash (authHash)
            if( authHash == null  ||  authHash.length() != AuthenticationFilter.DIGEST_LENGTH ) {
                LOG.log( Level.WARNING, "create user: wrong auth={0}", authHash );
                asynResp.resume( Response.status( Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST ).entity( Integer.toString( User.REST_RESPONSE_WRONG_AUTH ) ).build() );
                return;
            }

            email = email.toLowerCase();
            try {
                TypedQuery<User> tq = em.createNamedQuery( "User.findByEmail", User.class );
                    tq.setParameter( "email", email );
                User user = tq.getSingleResult();
                LOG.log( Level.WARNING, "create user: doublicate email={0}", email );
                asynResp.resume( Response.status( Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST ).entity( Integer.toString( User.REST_RESPONSE_OCCUPIED_EMAIL ) ).build() );
                return;
            }
            catch( NoResultException nre ) {
                // no user with same email found -> progesss registration...
            }


            // send confirmation email
            try {

                LOG.log( Level.FINE, "UCR.run: everything fine, process..." );
                // create & save user
                User user = new User();
                    user.setEmail( email );
                    user.setAuth( authHash );
                LOG.log( Level.FINE, "UCR.run: User created, persist..." );
                em.persist( user );
                LOG.log( Level.FINE, "UCR.run: ...persisted!" );

                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );
                String key = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary( md.digest( (System.currentTimeMillis()+email).getBytes() ) );

                UserEmailRegistration uer = new UserEmailRegistration();
                    uer.setUser( user );
                    uer.setDate( new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() ) );
                    uer.setKey( key );
                LOG.log( Level.FINE, "UCR.run: UserEmailReg created, persist..." );
                em.persist( uer );
                LOG.log( Level.FINE, "UCR.run: ...persisted!" );
                LOG.log( Level.FINE, "UCR.run: flush em..." );
                em.flush();
                LOG.log( Level.FINE, "UCR.run: ...flushed!" );

                // send registration email
                LOG.log( Level.FINE, "UCR.run: persisted User, send email..." );
                emailBean.sendRegistrationEmail( uer );

                LOG.log( Level.FINE, "UCR.run: everything done, resume..." );
                asynResp.resume( Response.ok( Integer.toString( user.getId() ) ).build() );

            }
            catch( MessagingException ex ) {
                LOG.log( Level.WARNING, "UCR.run: ", ex );
                ejbContext.setRollbackOnly();
                asynResp.resume( Response.status( Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST ).entity( User.REST_RESPONSE_WRONG_EMAIL ).build() );
            }
            catch( NoSuchAlgorithmException ex ) {
                LOG.log( Level.WARNING, "UCR.run: ", ex );
                ejbContext.setRollbackOnly();
                asynResp.resume( Response.status( Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR ).build() );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't think it is caused by the EmailBean but for the sake of completeness:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@TransactionAttribute( REQUIRED )
@ConcurrencyManagement( ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER )
public class EmailBean {

    private static final Logger     LOG = Logger.getLogger( "xyz" );


    @Resource( name = "java:jboss/mail/sendgrid" )
    Session mailSession;


    @EJB
    PropertyBean propBean;


    @Lock( LockType.READ )
    public void sendRegistrationEmail( final UserEmailRegistration uer ) throws MessagingException {

        LOG.log( Level.FINER, "send email: userId={0}, email={1}, category={2}", new Object[]{ uer.getUser().getId(), uer.getUser().getEmail(), "registration" } );

        MimeMessage mailMsg = new MimeMessage( mailSession );
            mailMsg.setSubject( "" );
            mailMsg.setContent( uer.getKey(), "text/html" );
            mailMsg.setRecipient( Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress( uer.getUser().getEmail() ) );

        Transport.send( mailMsg );

        LOG.log( Level.FINE, "sent email: userId={0}, email={1}, category={2}", new Object[]{ uer.getUser().getId(), uer.getUser().getEmail(), "registration" } );

    }

}
```

Comment: sry for the late reply... But creating a Runnable and submitting to a ManagedExecutorService is a well described pattern in Java EE 7. Did I miss out on something?

Comment: Sorry for introduced confusion: you're right. I think that it's related with the `EntityManager` being injected into REST resource and passed to `UserCreateRunnable` (other thread). Please try to extract business logic to EJB component (method marked with `@Asynchronous`), and inject `EntityManager` to this new EJB class.

Comment: again, sry for beeing late I'm doing this part time... Thanks for the lead, I tried to inject dependecies in an xtra Runnable class which did the job!